# Accessing only specific columns of a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I am trying to write a code to selectively append values from a list called epoch (provided below), based on the values in an array called outliers (provided below).

```
    import numpy as np
    epoch = [(np.array([[1, 2, 3],
             [4, 5, 6],
             [7, 8, 9]]),
      np.array([100, 101, 102])),
     (np.array([[10, 11, 12],
             [13, 14, 15],
             [16, 17, 18]]),
      np.array([103, 104, 105]))]

      outlier = np.array([10,32,56])
```

I want to append only those columns of epoch, to, say, E, if the corresponding values at the indices in outliers is less than or equal to 40. For example, as the third value in outlier (=56) is greater than 40, this is what I want:

```
E = [(np.array([[1, 2],
         [4, 5],
         [7, 8]]),
  np.array([100, 101])),
 (np.array([[10, 11],
         [13, 14],
         [16, 17]]),
  np.array([103, 104]))]
```

(The third column from inside of epoch been left out)

What I tried:

```
E = list()
j = 0
for idx, l in enumerate(epoch):
    epo = np.transpose(epoch[idx][0]) 
    for i in range(len(epo)):
        while j < 3:
            if outlier[j]<= 40:
                E.append(epoch[idx][:][i])
                j+=1                
            else:
                j+=1
```

What I got:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]])]
```

What I want:

```
E = [(np.array([[1, 2],
         [4, 5],
         [7, 8]]),
  np.array([100, 101])),
 (np.array([[10, 11],
         [13, 14],
         [16, 17]]),
  np.array([103, 104]))]
```

My actual lists (epoch and outlier) are very huge.

Comment: For a 2d array, you select columns with `arr[:, [1,2]]`.  `[:][[1,2]]` does not work.  `[:]` does nothing for both lists and arrays.  Spend more time with numpy intro dkcs.

Comment: Yes it doesn't make any difference if I remove the [:]

Comment: You need to specify a format of ```epoch```. It it always a list of tuples, where each tuple contains ```numpy.array```s? Then, why not doing like this? ```k = outlier <= 40; E = [tuple(a[..., k] for a in t) for t in epoch] ```

Comment: Yes it is always a list of tuples. When I tried your idea I got the following error: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed. Maybe I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: It seems you are using an ancient Numpy. Try the recent version. For an ancient version, try ```np.take(a, np.where(k), axis=-1)``` instead of ```a[..., k]```, although I'm not sure it will work.